# Kinect IR Emitter Continuous or Pulsed?

Tags: kinect

I'm a student intern and have a work project using Kinect cameras. Unfortunately I can't go into project details due to confidentiality, but need to know if the IR dot array that is emitted from the IR blasters within the Kinect is a continuous stream or pulsed? Just the emitted IR light, not the reception from the IR camera. It would be shining on some other IR light sensors within the environment that detect when something passes through their IR field of view, but I have been told that it would not interfere as long as the stream is continuous.

I would appreciate any help/ information you guys could give.

Answer (score 1):

The kinect 360 cameras has a static pattern of points that are unevenly distributed. The pattern is continuous and not pulsed as far as I know.